# how to remove previously added sd-bus match

Tags: dbus

I have created sd_bus and then registered for signals by specifying match using `sd_bus_add_match()` and getting signals from `sd-bus`. Now I want to know how to stop getting the events for specific match without invoking `sd_bus_close()`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can tell, reading source code, it seems you have got to pass a sd_bus_slot** to sd_bus_add_match; it will create one for you with type BUS_MATCH_CALLBACK.
Once you're done, just unref your sd_bus_slot and it will take care of destroying match and freeing all resources. See here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/a7753693547233e4a1d6e10b1a8f6515a477f227/src/libsystemd/sd-bus/bus-slot.c#L68 (note that bus_slot_disconnect is called by sd_bus_slot_unref().